# Build in NavMesh for 2d Games in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, 2d, path-finding, topdown

does any one of you know if I can use the build-in Navigation(pathfinding) system in Unity for a 2d Project (top-down)? Or do you know any assets, preferably free assets, who can help me out with that? Otherwise, I would use an A*-Star algorithm.
I also use a tilemap.
Thank you.

Cheers Fabian

Comment: No, you can't create a navmesh for a tilemap because it requires a mesh/mesh renderer, which will conflict with the sprite renderers used in most 2D components. [This guide](http://www.jgallant.com/nodal-pathfinding-in-unity-2d-with-a-in-non-grid-based-games/) walks through what appears to be pretty much a 2D recreation of NavMesh.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought so. Ok thanks a lot for the guide :)

Comment: Maybe consider 2.5D i.e. a 3D scene but you render it from the side.

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/h8man/NavMeshPlus) framework.